# AzureDevOps authentication issue when cloning to R

Tags: r, git, azure-devops

I have a repo in AzureDevOps that I created and have full access to. I am following the below instructions to clone the repo into R.

- From the Azure repo I am selecting 'Clone' and I am copying the url for the repo
- I then open a new session in R Studio, select 'New Project', 'Version control'.
- I then select git and then enter the repository url into the line.

R then says `fatal: Authentication failed for (repo name)`, but there is no option to add in my credentials anywhere so I'm not sure how to get passed this issue.

It might be worth noting that I have another repo from AzureDev cloned into R and I can push to that, so this isn't any kind of proxy issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your machine stored an obsolete credential.

You can go to **Control Panel**
, select **Credential Manager**, then click **Windows Credentials**, then remove the old credentials for your git repo under **Generic Credentials**.Below pic is for reference.

[image]

After the obsolete credential is removed,  You can then go back to R studio to clone your repo. You will be prompted to enter your credential.
[image]

However, besides above steps you can aslo tried using Personal Access Token to clone your `repo https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/Repo`